# Super simple VLOOKUP cannot retrieve the values as expected

Tags: excel, vlookup

This seemingly simple vlookup is not working and not picking up the specified value of 1 in ColA:

`=VLOOKUP(C1,A:B,0,FALSE)`

[image: VLOOKUP]

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: `VLookup()` always lookup value from first column. Your lookup value is in 2nd column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Index(), Match()` combination like below.

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C1,B:B,0))
```

[image]